# kafka - SaaS based multi tenant subscribers - Topic scaling

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a multi-tenant aware "subscribers (Web API micro-services)" to Kafka that will be hosted on Kubernetes. We are planning to have 1 topic per customer (tenant). This means all replicas for each micro-service must listen to *all* tenant topics. Let's say we have 10 Kubernetes replicas for "Service A". Since all 10 replicas belong to the same service (Service A), they will register with Kafka with the same consumer group name. (Say, 'Service-A-CG'). We could potentially have hundreds of tenants. Questions:

1. Does this mean we need to start 100's of threads for each "tenant" within a replica or can we subscribe to ALL topics on the same "subscriber" channel (singleton instance of "KafkaConsumer")?
2. At what point does a single subscriber instance starts choking unable to handle all these hundreds of "topics" on a single instance of KafkaConsumer? (Inside each replica for the same service)
3. Does this setup change if we have, let's say 500 replicas of Service-A?
4. Is there a way to have this "subscriber loop" only on 1 replica rather than starting this on all 10 replicas?
5. Is it better to have "subscribers" as "single replica" background services rather than "web api" services with multiple replicas? (of course, this single replica background service architecture means, there is now an I/O call to synch state from the Kafka message with other services)
   I am aware that in a "single partition per topic" scenario, Kafka delivers a message from a topic to only "1" replica.

Comment: Unclear how many partitions each of these topics has, but you cannot have replicas/threads > partitions

Comment: Yes, assuming number of partitions is always <= number of replicas and partitions

Comment: Ultimately, I dont think "topic per customer" is a good model. If you have a very popular service with millions of users, then Kafka would fail to handle that. Alternatively, if you have a smaller handful "event bus" topics handling actions for all customers, you run into the problem where one or more very "active" customers will slow down consuming events for others... It's a hard tradeoff between scalability and performance, and I'm not sure there is a right answer